# rsync only files newer than given date, with --delete

Tags: find, rsync

I'm trying to use rsync to backup only the files that have been created or changed 
after a certain date. The reason is that on that date, the whole system has been 
backed up. However, those global backup files are buried into archives, so they 
are not accessible for testing when rsync runs.

After a bit of research, manpage reading and trial-and-error I came up with this,
which *almost* works:

```
find "/directory-to-backed-up/" -type f -newer "<DATE-OF-LATEST-GLOBAL-BACKUP>" -print  | \
../rsync -v --progress --log-file=./rsync.log -rlt -z -m --chmod=a=rw,Da+x --delete \
    --files-from=- \
    --exclude-from=exclude.txt \
           / \
           "backuphost.lan::updateback/"
```

Why "almost"? My problem is that the --delete option fails to delete files no 
longer found at the source. I suspect this is because the names of files gone 
missing from the source aren't found by find, so they aren't fed to rsync as 
arguments.

How can I sync only files newer than a certain date, deleting from the destination
in backuphost.lan all the files that are no longer found at the source?

Comment: Slightly more readable than `find | rsync`, at least for me, is `rsync --files-from=<(find /path/to/files/ -type f -newer "datestamp" -print0)`.  Can't speak to why `--delete` isn't deleting, it certainly should be.

Comment: The files are not deleted because you are comparing existing (on the source) files only with your `rsync` command and not directory contents. However with every change in a directory's content, the dir's timestamp itself will be changed. So you can run your command with `find` but need to include directories (i.e. get rid of the `-type f` option.

Comment: @Fiximan - I had thought of this myself, but if I do as you suggest - namely, include directories in `find` (by suppressing the `-type f` option) -  rsync will backup files that are older than DATE-OF-LATEST-BACKUP.

Comment: I see. AFAIK `rsync` is at its boundaries then. Well, you could do it in two steps then and run a script using `diff local_dir remote_dir` (after selecting the dirs with your `find` command and the `-newer` restrictions) and search for files that are only in the `remote_dir`, then remove them selectively.

Comment: Yes, I guess I'll have to do it in two steps. First build a list, appending a / to directory names,
`find / \( -type d -printf "%p/\n" , -type f -print \) >files_and_dirs`
(GNU find only, I think), then I'll use rsync twice: (1) clean up the disappeared-from-source files running rsync on the directories only,
`rsync --delete --ignore-existing --existing --files-from=<(grep "/$" files_and_dirs) {...}`
(--delete, --ignore-existing and --existing when used together don't copy anything; they just delete files.)
(2) rsync the existing files
`rsync --files-from=<(grep "[^/]$" files_and_dirs)`

Comment: I prefer this over running find more than once, since it puts serious strain on the disks. As a result, the whole system slows down to a crawl.